# Удаление и поворот страниц PDF средствами PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Столкнулся с проблемой: нужна библиотека по работе с существующими PDF файлами.
Необходимо создать мини-редактор PDF с функцией поворота и удаления страниц .

Есть сторонние консольные приложения. Но интересно реализовать это средствами PHP

Comment: У PDF достаточно интересный синтаксис, - в нем есть прямая зависимость от количества символов, а также двойная система сжатия. Это по крайней мере то с чем я сталкивался. Не забывайте что + ко всему прочему вы столкнетесь со множеством версий этого формата. Есть библиотеки которые помогут вам вытащить текст и картинки, но этого не достаточно. Единственная библиотека, которая с этим сможет справиться - от ADobe - платная - ее не тестировал.

Comment: вот собственно [Документация](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) Эту документацию собственно изучал для более глубокого понимания формата. А вообще редактор очень актуальная тема - если найдете решение - выложите сюда решение , способ редактирования файла при помощи библиотеки или документацию. Все с чем я сталкивался - это было чтение документа, либо генерация с нуля, либо конвертирования из одного формата в другой

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с PDF средствами PHP существует библиотека FPDF (http://fpdf.org).

> FPDF is a PHP class which allows to generate PDF files with pure PHP, that is to say without using the PDFlib library. F from FPDF stands for Free: you may use it for any kind of usage and modify it to suit your needs.

Для корректной работы с кириллицей я использовал UFPDF - Unicode-расширение для этой библиотеки (http://acko.net/blog/ufpdf-unicode-utf-8-extension-for-fpdf/).

Answer (score 0):

Из ответа видно что FPDI и TCPDI одно и то же.

Для поворота ([источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111815/how-do-i-rotate-all-or-specific-pages-in-a-pdf-using-php)):

```
function rotatePDF($file, $degrees, $page = 'all'){

    $pdf = new TCPDI(); 
    $pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
    $pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

    $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($file);

    // rotate each page
    if($page=="all"){
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) { 
            $pageformat = array('Rotate'=>$degrees);
            $tpage = $pdf->importPage($i);
            $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tpage);
            //$info = $pdf->getPageDimensions();
            $orientation = $size['w'] > $size['h'] ? 'L' : 'P';

            $pdf->AddPage($orientation,$pageformat);
            $pdf->useTemplate($tpage);      
        }
    }else{
        $rotateFlag = 0;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagecount; $i++) { 
            if($page == $i){
                $pageformat = array('Rotate'=>$degrees);
                $tpage = $pdf->importPage($i);
                $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tpage);
                //$info = $pdf->getPageDimensions();
                $orientation = $size['w'] > $size['h'] ? 'L' : 'P';

                $pdf->AddPage($orientation,$pageformat);
                $pdf->useTemplate($tpage);
                $rotateFlag = 1;
            }else{
                if($rotateFlag==1){
                    // page after rotation; restore rotation
                    $rotateFlag = 0;
                    $pageformat = array('Rotate'=>0);

                    $tpage = $pdf->importPage($i);
                    $pdf->AddPage($orientation,$pageformat);
                    $pdf->useTemplate($tpage);
                }else{
                    // pages before rotation and after restoring rotation
                    $tpage = $pdf->importPage($i);
                    $pdf->AddPage();
                    $pdf->useTemplate($tpage);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $out = realpath($file);

    if(rename($file,"files/1/file.bak")){
        $result = $pdf->Output($out, "F"); 
        if($result == "" ){
            echo "ok";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Failed to rename old PDF";
        die;
    }
}

$file = "files/1/1.pdf";
rotatePDF($file,90); // rotating all works fine
rotatePDF($file,180,3); // rotates only page 3
```

Для удаления ([источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317522/delete-pages-using-fpdf)):

```
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('document.pdf');

//  Array of pages to skip -- modify this to fit your needs
$skipPages = [3,15,17,22];

//  Add all pages of source to new document
for( $pageNo=1; $pageNo<=$pageCount; $pageNo++ )
{
    //  Skip undesired pages
    if( in_array($pageNo,$skipPages) )
        continue;

    //  Add page to the document
    $templateID = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);
    $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateID);
    $pdf->addPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($templateID);
}

$pdf->Output();
```

Comment: Как обычно, дьявол скрывается в мелочах. Код вроде логичный, но заставить работать его не получилось. Явно этот код работает на какой то определенной версии. У меня PHP 5.6 и композером я устанавливал "setasign/fpdi-fpdf": "1.5.4" и "setasign/fpdi-fpdf": "1.6.1"...

Comment: Отлаживайте и смотрите где он падает.

Comment: Еще насторожило то, что при выполнении скрипта издается ужасный звук (как морзянка:D )

Comment: А что издавало звук? :)

Comment: С удаление разобрался.... проблема была как раз в строке `$pdf->Output();` в ней обязательно должны быть параметры. `$pdf->Output($filename,'F')`

Comment: Звук я так подозреваю издавала система при попытке сохранить изменения в файл.

Comment: Интересно, ни разу такого не встречал, может она использует старые interrupts вызовы для чего-то?